# What does the Black shield icon mean for clan war availability?

Tags: clash-of-clans

- Green shield = opted in
- red shield = opted out
- black shield = ?

What does the black shield mean? Are they in a war in another clan?

Comment: Umm... What are you trying to say? "The cat hasn't got any pocket change" makes about as much sense as what you have just said. Please add some more information to help explain what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @Ben "The cat hasn't got any pocket change" makes perfect sense to me

Comment: While it's sorta possible to figure out what's being said here, it's rather low quality.

Answer (score 5):

the Small Shield in one's profile and in the list of clan members comes in 3 states,

- **Red** - the player has Opt-Out of Clan Wars regardless of Trophy Count
- **Green** - the player as Opt-In of Clan Wars
- **Black** - the player is ineligible for Clan Wars

While I have never seen the Black Shield in my own profile, when I have seen it with other members it has normally been for new members who had came from another clan. there is also a small bar under the Black Shield which is how long that person still has to wait before they can choose to Opt-In/Out of clan wars.

Should Note that a Clan Leader can override a player's Clan War Prference

> **Note:** Leaders can still choose players that have chosen to opt-out by default, and can always leave out players that have chosen to opt-in by default.

Source: [Clan Wars - Eligiblity of Members Point 2](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars)

Answer (score 2):

Black means they are a part of a war in another clan and as we know we cannot be in two wars at a time so the player is not eligible for war in any other clan he joins. They can join next war only if the time of current war they are a part of ends.

http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars

**Eligibility of Members**

> Members are also not eligible for a war if they have left a clan with
>   the member currently participating in a war; this status remains until
>   that clan finishes their war (e.g. if Player A leaves Clan A that is
>   currently in war with 1 day left and joins Clan B, Player A will not
>   be eligible in Clan B's wars until 1 day has passed).

Answer (score 0):

Black means they are new to the clan and aren't eligible for wars yet.
They will be eligible by the time your next war starts.

Answer (score -1):

Black means they came from another clan and started a war then left, they will be eligible for war once the other clan they came from is done with war.